# Save recording response log in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, save, test-results

I know how to save the results tree before doing recording in Jmeter. But is there a way to save the results after the recording?? Actually I have recorded a big scrip without knowing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as a child of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and you will be able to see request/response details and save them into a file if needed.

[image]

Just in case the above test plan was generated using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

[image]